# SweetAlert2 en Vista Blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, blade, sweetalert2

Hola necesito utilizar en una vista blade sweetalert2 y no quiero hacerlo por CDN sino por instalación NPM.

Pero no entiendo como hacerlo le pongo esto:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
```

En el archivo app.js. Pero si lo intento exportar me da error de modulos de JS. Alguien podría decirme como integrar SweetAlert2 en blade. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El `import swal from 'sweetalert2';`
es para poder usar la librería de sweetalert dentro de tu codigo, es como una manera de cargarla, pero necesitas descargarla por npm

```
npm install sweetalert2
```